# How to Install multiple versions of .Net SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, .net-framework

I am trying to build a .Net application that requires a specific version of the .Net SDK, namely: `"version": "2.2.107"`

A recent apt update has updated the installed .Net SDK version to the latest available which is `2.2.300`.

Is it possible to to install multiple versions of the same SDK?

I can have multiple minor SDK versions installed as shown here

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.700 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
2.2.300 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I am trying to avoid having to uninstall my current installed version just to build this application.

As a side note, the Microsoft download page does not give instructions for installing a specific version, which I suspect is a bug. The shown commands will always install the latest version even if you got to that page by clicking on the version you actually want to install.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-2.2.107

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every package manager like APT or RPM deals with the newest (and only newest) version of package. It applies to .Net Core packages so you cannot have older and newer version of package at the same time.  Microsoft has prepared script to install .Net Core binaries (.Net Core, ASP.NET Core SDKs and Runtimes) without package managers. You can download this script from here:

https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh

With this script you can specify what version you want to install (option -v or –version) and where you want to install binaries (options -i or –install-dir).

- Uninstall existing packages with “apt remove dotnet-”,
- Install chosen binaries specified with “—version” option to the same folder (/usr/share/dotnet).

The script is very sophisticated and can be run with much more options. Specify “—help” with the first run to read about this.
Notice: script will add installation folder to current $PATH environment variable but not to the profile file of your shell. You should do this manually.

Comment: This worked well - thank you. The complete command I used is: `sudo ./dotnet-install.sh -v 2.2.107 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with package manager which uninstall older version before installing newer one. You can use botnet-install scripts provided by Microsoft to fetch and install dotnet binary packages independently from package manager. All instructions you can find here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

Comment: Including the actual steps to solve the problem will make this an answer. Right now, it is a "link-only" answer and likely to be closed unless it is improved.